# How to rotate a object on the circumference of a circle?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I created a function for drawing a circle in oepnGL java, and I want to rotate another circle on the circumference of a circle ?

This is my function for create circle, how to change it for drawing the circle on circumference?

For example create a new circle using as center coordinates points from first circle ?

```
private void rotateAroundOz(GL2 gl, int r, double cx, double cy) {
        int step = 1;

        gl.glLineWidth(5);
        gl.glBegin(GL.GL_LINE_LOOP);
            for (int i=0; i<360; i+=step) {
                gl.glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
                gl.glVertex2d(cx + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)), cy + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i)));
            }
        gl.glEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to draw a circle (with `rotateAroundOz()`) using a position that you compute from

`cx + r * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(i)), cy + r * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(i))`

```
// This is the attributes of the invisible circle: "PositionCircle" 
//that will gives you the circumference
float positionCircle_Radius = 1.0;
float positionCircle_CenterX = 0.0;
float positionCircle_CenterY = 0.0;

// This is actually the circle that you want to draw from the
// "PositionCircle"
int positionOnCircumferenceInDegrees = 90;
float drawnCircle_Radius = 2.0;
float drawnCircle_CenterX = positionCircle_CenterX + positionCircle_Radius * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(positionOnCircumferenceInDegrees));
float drawnCircle_CenterY = positionCircle_CenterY + positionCircle_Radius * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(positionOnCircumferenceInDegrees));

rotateAroundOz(gl, drawnCircle_Radius, drawnCircle_CenterX, drawnCircle_CenterY)
```

So you can add `positionOnCircumferenceInDegrees` and `drawnCircle_Radius` as parameters for your new function.

(That's my first response ever on SO :p hope it's comprehensible!)